# Windows patching on multiple servers

Tags: powershell

We have about 1000+ servers and they patch by WSUS. In WSUS we assigned the patch and after that we login to the servers and download n Install the patches. Once it done we restart the machine as per the schedule.

I want to automate downloading of patch and installation of patch. I got some script but not sure is this the best or any other way is also available.

Here is the script:

```
$UpdateSession = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.Session
$UpdateSearcher = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()

Write-Host("Searching for applicable updates...") -Fore Green

$SearchResult = $UpdateSearcher.Search("IsInstalled=0 and Type='Software'")

Write-Host("")
Write-Host("List of applicable items on the machine:") -Fore Green
For ($X = 0; $X -lt $SearchResult.Updates.Count; $X++){
    $Update = $SearchResult.Updates.Item($X)
    Write-Host( ($X + 1).ToString() + "&gt; " + $Update.Title)
}

If ($SearchResult.Updates.Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host("There are no applicable updates.")
    Exit
}

#Write-Host("")
#Write-Host("Creating collection of updates to download:") -Fore Green

$UpdatesToDownload = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl

For ($X = 0; $X -lt $SearchResult.Updates.Count; $X++){
    $Update = $SearchResult.Updates.Item($X)
    #Write-Host( ($X + 1).ToString() + "&gt; Adding: " + $Update.Title)
    $Null = $UpdatesToDownload.Add($Update)
}

Write-Host("")
Write-Host("Downloading Updates...")  -Fore Green

$Downloader = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateDownloader()
$Downloader.Updates = $UpdatesToDownload
$Null = $Downloader.Download()

#Write-Host("")
#Write-Host("List of Downloaded Updates...") -Fore Green

$UpdatesToInstall = New-Object -Com Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl

For ($X = 0; $X -lt $SearchResult.Updates.Count; $X++){
    $Update = $SearchResult.Updates.Item($X)
    If ($Update.IsDownloaded) {
        #Write-Host( ($X + 1).ToString() + "&gt; " + $Update.Title)
        $Null = $UpdatesToInstall.Add($Update)        
    }
}

$Install = [System.String]$Args[0]
$Reboot  = [System.String]$Args[1]

If (!$Install){
    $Install = Read-Host("Would you like to install these updates now? (Y/N)")
}

If ($Install.ToUpper() -eq "Y" -or $Install.ToUpper() -eq "YES"){
    Write-Host("")
    Write-Host("Installing Updates...") -Fore Green

    $Installer = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateInstaller()
    $Installer.Updates = $UpdatesToInstall

    $InstallationResult = $Installer.Install()

    Write-Host("")
    Write-Host("List of Updates Installed with Results:") -Fore Green

    For ($X = 0; $X -lt $UpdatesToInstall.Count; $X++){
        Write-Host($UpdatesToInstall.Item($X).Title + ": " + $InstallationResult.GetUpdateResult($X).ResultCode)
    }

    Write-Host("")
    Write-Host("Installation Result: " + $InstallationResult.ResultCode)
    Write-Host("    Reboot Required: " + $InstallationResult.RebootRequired)

    If ($InstallationResult.RebootRequire -eq $True){
        If (!$Reboot){
            $Reboot = Read-Host("Would you like to install these updates now? (Y/N)")
        }

        If ($Reboot.ToUpper() -eq "Y" -or $Reboot.ToUpper() -eq "YES"){
            Write-Host("")
            Write-Host("Rebooting...") -Fore Green
            (Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem).Reboot()
        }
    }
}
```

Is this script will able to perform activity on multiple servers? Can we fetch the report regarding download successful/install successful.

Is there any other options to perform the same activity?

Comment: `Is there any other options to perform the same activity?` Yes. `Is this script will able to perform activity on multiple servers? Can we fetch the report regarding download successful/ install successful` I don't know, have you actually *tried*? Please don't just dump a script and ask if it will do x,y, or z. What are you actually asking for?

Comment: Actually i can't test it now because microsoft will release update in dec second week. This script work fine on single machine.

Comment: As the script is written, I don't think it will update multiple machines when invoked from a single machine.  I think you will need to look at Invoke-Command and Start-Job in order to start the jobs that will invoke the scriptblock command on other computers.

Comment: @JoshPetitt Thanks for your comment. I know it can be run by Invote-command but want to know is there any other way? Invoke command fail on some of the machines.

Comment: The `-WhatIf` common parameter may be helpful in this situation. `help about_CommonParameters`

Comment: @404 What error do you get when you `invoke-command` on another machine? You should include the error message in the _original post_. If it is because you don't have rights, then no other command will help.